# Magento V1.9 one page checkout not displaying credit card form - Rest ksort error

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net

I'm having a few issues after upgrading to 1.9.2.2

When going through the checkout process when I get to payment method and select Credit Card no form appears.
If I click Continue then I get a popup saying Expiration date is wrong.

I also have 2 paypal errors (10001 and 10002), but will post them in a separate question.

Ultimo Theme (latest)
Same problem when I switched to default theme.

Payment Methods > Paypal Standard/Express and Authorize.net both enabled
Live API credentials in place
Sandbox/Testing = off.
System > Advanced = all enabled expect Moneybookers and Google Checkout.

System log error

```
ERR (3): Warning: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given  in .../downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php on line 240
```

The section of the Rest.php is

```
$out = array();
        foreach ($return as $name=>$package) {
            $stabilities = array_map(array($this, 'shortStateToLong'), array_keys($package));
            $versions = array_map('trim', array_values($package));
            $package = array_combine($versions, $stabilities);
            ksort($package);
            $out[$name] = $package;
        }
        return $out;
```

Any ideas? This is a live site for a client and I really need to get it live again asap.

Answer (score 0):

Hi PTeam and welcome to MageOverflow. Unfortunately I don't think we can help you much, because wen either maintain or support Ultimo Theme nor your payment provider (I assume you don't use save CC, because then you would need PCI compliance).

But a few hints:

GoogleCheckout is as far as I know not part of Magento anymore.

```
ERR (3): Warning: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given  in .../downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php on line 240
```

This error is from downloader, means from magento connect and should have therefore no connection to your problem.

So I would start debugging in frontend and make sure it is no JS/CSS issue. Means the form is there but invisible.

If you know this, start your local xdebug (if not installed already, INSTALL IT) and then check, whether the form is included, just put a breakpoint into the template.

If this is not the case, then you need to check, whether the payment method is active, breakpoint in `isActive`(?) in `Mage_Payment_Model_Payment_Abstract`(?)

Comment: Thanks Fabien. It does the same thing in the default theme, so it's not a theme issue. I'm looking into Xdebug.